# Flask on Raspberry Pi changing standard page

Tags: python, flask, raspberry-pi

On my RPi (b model) Flask is installed.

I can access the webpage "It works" via another browser on another computer.
Works great. As well on my LAN as from the outside world.
And also, I can write and run Python scripts and let it act as server and so on.

But how do I enable my own Python script for Flask as standard at boot from RPi.
It's seated in the /home/pi/myproject dir and I'd like it to be standard.

I can't find the standard python script and templates to replace.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: What do you mean to do  basically ?

Comment: flask runs a server, which is being build by a python script and html templates. I'd like to replace these.

Comment: Replace them with what ? Thats what I am asking